# Merge dataframes with multiple combinations in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge Dataframe 1 and 2 into the expected output.

Dataframe 1

```
Parent  Family Name

Jack    Everdeen
Rita    Lawrence
Amy     Donnie
Eric    Everdeen
Nash    Donnie
Andrew  Paul
Lily    Donnie
```

Datafram 2

```
Child   Family Name

Vivian  Everdeen
Alex    Donnie
Rose    Evans
Annie   Paul
Hugh    Lawrence
Billy   Donnie
Marc    Paul
```

Expected Output

Note that "Vivian", "Alex" and "Billy" have more that 1 row because there are more than one parent who have the same family name with the child.

```
Child   Family Name  Possible Parent
Vivian  Everdeen     Jack
Vivian  Everdeen     Eric
Alex    Donnie       Amy
Alex    Donnie       Nash
Alex    Donnie       Lily
Rose    Evans        0
Annie   Paul         Andrew
Hugh    Lawrence     Rita
Billy   Donnie       Amy
Billy   Donnie       Nash
Billy   Donnie       Lily
Marc    Paul         Andrew
```

My code is as follows.

```
import pandas as pd

data_1 = [['Jack','Everdeen'],['Rita','Lawrence'],['Amy','Donnie'],['Eric','Everdeen'],['Nash','Donnie'],['Andrew','Paul'],['Lily','Donnie']]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1,columns=['Parent','Family Name'],dtype=float)
data_2 = [['Vivian','Everdeen'],['Alex','Donnie'],['Rose','Evans'],['Annie','Paul'],['Hugh','Lawrence'],['Billy','Donnie'],['Marc','Paul']]
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2,columns=['Child','Family Name'],dtype=float)

pd.concat([df_1,df_2])
```

However, the output is as follows.

```
    Parent  Family Name Child

0   Jack    Everdeen    NaN
1   Rita    Lawrence    NaN
2   Amy     Donnie      NaN
3   Eric    Everdeen    NaN
4   Nash    Donnie      NaN
5   Andrew  Paul        NaN
6   Lily    Donnie      NaN
0   NaN     Everdeen    Vivian
1   NaN     Donnie      Alex
2   NaN     Evans       Rose
3   NaN     Paul        Annie
4   NaN     Lawrence    Hugh
5   NaN     Donnie      Billy
6   NaN     Paul        Marc
```

Please help me to merge the 2 dataframes into the expected output.

Comment: Why not simply `merge` on *Family Name*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get that done with a left merge.

```
df_2.merge(df_1, how='left').fillna(0)
```

**Result**

```
     Child Family Name  Parent
0   Vivian    Everdeen    Jack
1   Vivian    Everdeen    Eric
2     Alex      Donnie     Amy
3     Alex      Donnie    Nash
4     Alex      Donnie    Lily
5     Rose       Evans       0
6    Annie        Paul  Andrew
7     Hugh    Lawrence    Rita
8    Billy      Donnie     Amy
9    Billy      Donnie    Nash
10   Billy      Donnie    Lily
11    Marc        Paul  Andrew
```